# Prime numbers in perl

Tags: perl, for-loop, numbers, primes

I am new to Perl. I am trying to print all the prime numbers between `2` and `N` (user input). See below for my sample code.

With the code that follows whenever a user inputs a number the console prints the same number. For *e.g.* if I enter `7` the script prints `7` and not all the prime numbers from `2` up to `7`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

print "Enter the number till which you want to generate prime numbers"; 
$n=<STDIN>; 
chomp($n); 
print "The prime numbers between 2 and $n are:\n";
for($i=3;$i<=n;$i++) 
{ 
  for($j=2;$j<$n;$j++) 
 { 
  if(($i%$j)==0) 
   { 
     last;   # breaking out of the inner loop. 
   } 
 } 
 if($j==$n) 
  { 
    print "$i\n"; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out CPAN, it has lots of useful stuff like libraries to generate primes.

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e 'install Math::Prime::Util'
$ perl -MMath::Prime::Util=:all -E 'say for @{ primes ( 0, 1000)} '
```

https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Prime::Util

Answer (score 3):

One of [Abigail's .sigs](http://diswww.mit.edu/bloom-picayune.mit.edu/perl/10138) has a ***regex*** (!) that determines whether a number is prime:

```
perl -le 'map {  print "Prime $_" if (1 x $_) !~ /^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/ } 1..10001'
```

That takes about 15 seconds on my system. Of course, as [evil-otto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796950/evil-otto) points out, there are faster solutions.

There is a very good explanation of how the regex works on [Neil Kandalgaonkar](http://neilk.net/)'s excellent blog<sup>1</sup>. The workings of Abigail's marvelous brain are left unexplained.

---

1). See: [Abigail's regex to test for prime numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731220717/https://neilk.net/blog/2000/06/01/abigails-regex-to-test-for-prime-numbers/).

Link uses WayBack which is required. Original reference:
http://neilk.net/blog/2000/06/01/abigails-regex-to-test-for-prime-numbers/

Comment: Small optimization: No point backtracking in the `\1+` expression. If it doesn't fit the end of the string, it never will. Use `\1++` instead. Heh.

Answer (score 0):

You get the maximum number and put it into a variable `$n`

Your only "print" statement is in a loop that says

```
if($j==$n) 
 { 
   print "$i\n"; 
 }
```

If `$i` (the number you are testing) is 3, `$j` (the counter you are using to test values) is 3, and `$n` is 7, then it will not tell you that 3 is prime.

Comment: Please give me an updated code which will help me print all prime numbers starting from 2 to a particular number.(say 15).

Comment: print "2 3 5 7 11 13\n";  I'm not going to write your code for you.  I told you exactly what and where the problem is.  This is the part where you learn how to program.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
print "Enter the number till which you want to generate prime numbers"; 
$n=<STDIN>; 
chomp($n); 
print "The prime numbers between 2 and $n are:\n";
for($i=3;$i<=$n;$i++) 
{ 
    $is_prime = 1;
    for($j=2;$j<=sqrt($i);$j++){
        if($i % $j == 0){
            $is_prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($is_prime == 1) {
        print $i."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm still waiting for the 10001st prime to be calculated....so I think this might consume allot of juice...bluh.. but here goes:

```
$a = 2;
$count = 0;


until($count eq 10) #choose the number of primes you want.. 

{
$var = 0;
  for($i = 1; $i < $a+1; $i++)
    {
        if($a % $i eq 0)
        {
            $var++;
        }

    }

  if($var eq 2)
  {
    $count++;
  }
  if($count eq 10) #if number of primes is reached... 
  {
    print "\n\nValue = $a\n\n";
  }

$a++;
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @prime_list;
my $n = <STDIN>;

for my $i (2..$n){

    my $check="true"; #check if it is prime number
    for (2..$i-1){
       if($i % $_ ==0){
          $check = "false"; # means its not prime;
          last;
       }
    }

    if ($check eq "true"){
       push @prime_list, $i;
    }
}

print "the prime list: @prime_list.\n";
```